# I want to add functionality in Quicksearch box to search using any data column not just name

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I want to quicksearch using any column name(like description, Status) current search is being performed using Name only

class ApplicationList(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

```
# parser_classes = (JSONParser,)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    # Get a list of fields dynamically
    fields = list()
    for f in Application._meta.fields:
        if f.is_relation:
            continue
        fields.append(f.name)

    queryset = Application.objects_with_sprint_name.all()

    # Looking for a specific bubble?
    if 'bubble' in request.data:
        if request.data['bubble'] == '4-1':
            queryset = queryset.filter(assessment_phase__id=request.data['bubble']).exclude(attributes__contains={'application_disposition':'Removed'})
        else:
            queryset = queryset.filter(assessment_phase__id=request.data['bubble'])

    # Providing a search query?
    if 'search' in request.data:
        q_search = request.data['search']

        # Build the query
        q = get_query(q_search, fields)
        queryset = queryset.filter(q)

    if 'filter' in request.data:
        q = get_filter(request.data['filter'])
        if q:
            queryset = queryset.filter(q)

    page = int(request.data.get('page', 1))
    per_page = int(request.data.get('per_page', 25))

    # Sorting
    sort_by = request.data.get('sort_by', 'name') or 'name'
    sort_dir = request.data.get('sort_dir', 'asc') or 'asc'

    if sort_dir == 'desc':
        sort_dir = '-'
    else:
        sort_dir = ''

    # Is this an actual field or do we need to sort by the attributes__*?
    if sort_by not in fields:
        sort_by = 'attributes__' + sort_by

    queryset = queryset.order_by('{0}{1}'.format(sort_dir, sort_by))

    # Do a little data massaging
    untreated_data = queryset.values()

    data = list()
    for app in untreated_data:
        this_app = {}
        for k, v in app.items():
            if k == 'attributes':
                continue
            if k == 'sprint_name':
                this_app[k] = v
                this_app['sprint'] = v
                continue

            this_app[k] = v
        this_app.update(app['attributes'])

        data.append(this_app)

    start = (page-1) * per_page
    end = (page) * per_page

    response = {
        'total_rows': len(data),
        'data': data[start:end],
    }
    return Response(response)
```

def get_query(query_string, search_fields):
    ''' Returns a query, that is a combination of Q objects. That combination
        aims to search keywords within a model by testing the given search fields.

```
'''
query = None  # Query to search for every search term
terms = normalize_query(query_string)
for term in terms:
    or_query = None  # Query to search for a given term in each field
    for field_name in search_fields:
        q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % field_name: term})
        if or_query is None:
            or_query = q
        else:
            or_query = or_query | q
    if query is None:
        query = or_query
    else:
        query = query & or_query
return query
```

def get_filter(filter_dict):
    available_fields = [ field.name for field in Application._meta.fields ] \
                       + ApplicationManager.annotated_fields

```
query = None
if filter_dict is None:
    return query

for field_name, val in filter_dict.items():
    query_field = field_name

    # Quicksearch box
    if field_name == '_quicksearch_':
        q = Q(name__icontains=val)

        if query is None:
            query = q
        else:
            query = query & q

        continue

    # Figure out if this field is part of the model
    # or in the attributes json field
    if query_field not in available_fields:
        query_field = 'attributes__{0}'.format(query_field)

    if isinstance(val, list):
        q = None
    #
    #     # Are we looking for null or blank?
        if '#is_null_or_blank#' in val:
            val.remove('#is_null_or_blank#')
            q = Q(**{"%s__isnull" % query_field: True}) | \
                Q(**{query_field: ''}) | \
                Q(**{query_field: []})
    #
    #     # Loop through the list and create some "OR" expressions
        for v in val:
            tmp = Q(**{"%s__contains" % query_field: v})
            if q is None:
                q = tmp
            q = q | tmp

    elif val.startswith('#bool#'):
        bval = val[6:].lower() == 'true'
        q = Q(**{"%s" % query_field: bval})
    else:
        q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % query_field: val})

    # # Add to our master query of all fields
    if query is None:
        query = q
    else:
        query = query & q

return query
```

Answer (score 0):

# Quicksearch box
    if field_name == '*quicksearch*':
        q = Q(name__icontains=val) | Q(attributes__icontains=val), I got the field wrong which I corrected and for foreign key relationship [django foreignkey contains query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773262/django-foreignkey-contains-query) helped